# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Dispatch threw exception in spring hibernate

Tags: mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations

Hi i am writing a spring mvc hibernate annotation application there i have 2 tables **"team"** and another table **"Employee"**.Here i am using **one-to-one** mapping and **mysql** database.In **Employee** table i am keeping employee records like name,Team etc.The **"team"** table contains two entries **teamid**(primary key)and **teamname**.Here I am using a dropdown to select the team name in the **Employee.jsp** page.when i delete a team name i want to delete all its references from the employee table.when i run the program i am getting the following error

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Dispatch threw exception in spring hibernate
```

Details

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Dispatch threw exception
    root cause 

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addTeamController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Could not autowire field: private com.resource.ResourceService.AddTeamService com.resource.ResourceController.AddTeamController.teamServices; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'teamService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Could not autowire field: private com.resource.ResourceDao.AddTeamDao com.resource.ResourceService.AddTeamServiceImpl.teamdao; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'teamDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.resource.ResourceDao.AddTeamImpl.sessiofactory; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource 
    [/WEB-INF/dispatch/Dispatch-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
    nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.resource.ResourceBean.AddTeam, at table: Employee, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(teams)]
```

and the same error is repeating for my **service class**,**dao class**.

Database schema

Employee table

```
CREATE TABLE `Employee` (  `empId` int(11) NOT NULL,  
 `empName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  `empExp` int(11) NOT NULL, 
 `empTeam`      varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `teamId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`empId`));
```

Team Table

```
    CREATE TABLE `Team` (  `teamId` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `teamName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`teamId`)  , KEY `FK901` (`teamId`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK901` FOREIGN KEY (`teamId`) REFERENCES `Employee` (`empId`));
```

AddTeam.java

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="Team")

public class AddTeam {


    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @Column(name="teamId")



    private Integer teamId;

    @Column(name="teamName")
    private String teamName;

    public Integer getTeamId() {
          return teamId;
         }

         public void setTeamId(Integer teamId) {
          this.teamId = teamId;
         }

         public String getTeamName() {
          return teamName;
         }

         public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
          this.teamName = teamName;
         }
              }
```

Resource.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Resource implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -723583058586873479L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="empid")
    private Integer empId;

    @Column(name="empname")
    private String empName;

    @Column(name="empexp")
    private Integer empExp;



    @Column(name="empteam")
    private String empTeam;


     @JoinColumn(name="teamId")
     private AddTeam teams;



    public Integer getEmpId(){
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(Integer empId){
        this.empId=empId;
    }


    public String getEmpName(){
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName){
        this.empName=empName;
    }

    public Integer getEmpExp(){
        return empExp;
    }
    public void setEmpExp(Integer empExp){
        this.empExp=empExp;
    }



    public String getEmpTeam(){
        return empTeam;
    }
    public void setEmpTeam(String empTeam){
        this.empTeam=empTeam;
    }


    public AddTeam getTeams() {
          return teams;
         }

         public void setTeams(AddTeam teams) {
          this.teams = teams;
         }

}
```

and this is the query used in ResourceDaoImpl.java

```
@Override
    public void deleteResource(int resourceid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE FROM Resource WHERE empid=" +resourceid).executeUpdate();

        }
```

Query used to delete in AddTeamDaoImpl.java

```
@Override
    public void deleteTeams(int teamid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sessiofactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE FROM AddTeam WHERE teamid="+teamid).executeUpdate();

    }
```

deletefunction in ResourceController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteResourceDetails(@ModelAttribute("command")  Resource resource,
            BindingResult result){
        resourceServices.deleteResource(resource.getEmpId());
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("resourcekey", resourceServices.listResources());
        model.put("teamKey", addteamServices.listTeams());
        return new  ModelAndView("EditTeam",model);
    }
```

Team.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
      <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Emoloyee details</title>

<center>
<h2>Add Team Details</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="Team.html">
   <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="teamId">Team ID:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="teamId" id="demo" value="${team.teamId}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="teamName">Team Name:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="teamName" value="${team.teamName}"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><input type="submit" value="SAVE"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </form:form>
        <br/>
  <c:if test="${!empty teamKey}">
    <table align="center" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${teamKey}" var="team">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${team.teamId}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${team.teamName}"/></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="editTeam.html?teamId=${team.teamId}">Edit</a> |
                 <a href="deleteTeam.html?teamId=${team.teamId}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
<h2><a href="updateresource.html">Adding Publication</a></h2>


</center>



</body>
</html>
```

EmployeeDetail.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Resource Manager</title>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<h2>Add Resources</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="save.html">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><form:label path="empId">Employee Id</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="empId" id="demo" value= "${resource.empId }"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form:label path="empName">Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="empName" value="${resource.empName }"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><form:label path="empExp">Experience</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="empExp" value="${resource.empExp }"/></td>
  </tr>


   <tr>
    <td><form:label path="empTeam">Team</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="empTeam" value="${resource.empTeam}"/></td>
  </tr>


    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form:label path="teams.teamId">Team Name</form:label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:select path="teams.teamId" cssStyle="width: 150px;">    
                            <option value="-1">Select a type</option>
                            <c:forEach items="${teamKey}" var="teams">
                            <option value="${teams.teamId}">${teams.teamName}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </form:select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>


   <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"value="Submit"></td>

    </tr>

 </table>
 </form:form>
<br/>

 <c:if test="${!empty resourcekey}">
    <table align="center" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th> Emp ID</th>
            <th>Emp Name</th>
            <th>Emp Exp</th>
            <th>Emp Team</th>
            <th>Emp TeamNmae</th>
            <th>Emp skills</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${resourcekey}" var="resource">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${resource.empId}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${resource.empName}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${resource.empExp}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${resource.empTeam}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${resource.teams.teamName}"/></td>



                <td align="center"><a href="editPublication.html?empId=${resource.empId}">Edit</a> | <a href="deleteResource.html?empId=${resource.empId}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>

    <h2><a href="addTeam.html">Adding Category</a></h2>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

when i delete a team name i want to delete all its references from the employee table.
Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Stacktrace tells that hibernate can't map your entities.

In your **Entities**:

**Team**:  remove the `@OneToOne` for your `teamId`. Only:

```
@Id    
@Column(name="teamId")
private Integer teamId;
```

is enough.

In your code, with [`@OneToOne`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone) in the annotations, it means team is linked with itself(even not, it is used for association to another persistent class), which doesn't make sense.

**Employee:**

Because what you need is many employees for one team, so it's actually a `@ManyToOne` for the column `teamId` in your table `Employee`, like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "teamId")
private AddTeam teams;
```

if you like, you can use `@GeneratedValue` for your IDs.

For deleting all the reference, you can use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in `@ManyToOne`.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

for more details about [`@ManyToOne`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)